# Swift iOS -How to Handle GCD Sending Data To Firebase When App Is Shut Down Because Phone Is Shut Down?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous, grand-central-dispatch

I use GCD DispatchWorkItem to send some data to Firebase. I first send a pic to Firebase Storage and receive the metadata in the completion handler and turn it into a url and then into a string. I then send that url string to Firebase Database. I've tested my GCD method while going to the background, commenting out the firstCall so that it's problemCall fires, and also commenting out the secondCall so that it's problemCall fires etc and everything works fine. However I'm unsure of what to do if the app stops while one of network calls are being performed because the user shuts off the phone.

I'll explain it in steps:

1. The user presses a sendButton, an image gets initialized, then converted into data. I have a global flag that gets sets to true when the button is pressed. It was initially set to false and gets set back to false if there is a problem or if it reaches the callback of the secondCall.
2. The firstCall is a DispatchWorkItem(DWI) that take the data and sends it to FB Storage.
3. At the end of the firstCall I call firstCall.perform() so it can run. Right below that I initialize a problemCall as a DWI that fires off in 10 secs. If it fires it will cancel the firstCall, change the global flag to false, and show an error alert.
4. Inside the callback for the firstCall, if it's reached successfully I cancel the problemCall.
5. Assuming the firstCall is completed in less then 10 seconds I then initialize a secondCall as a DWI.
6. Inside the secondCall I take the url from the firstCall and send it to the FB Database.
7. At the bottom of the secondCall I call secondCall.perform() so it can now run. Right below that I again initialize the problemCall with another DWI that will fire off in 20 secs. If it fires off it will cancel the secondCall, change the global flag to false, and show an alert
8. Inside the callback for the secondCall, if it's reached successfully I cancel the problemCall and then self.wereGoodNowDoSomething() runs, and change the globe class to false.

AClass:

```
let storageRef = myFbStorageRef()
let dbRef = myFbDatabaseRef()
var firstCall: DispatchWorkItem?
var secondCall: DispatchWorkItem?
var problemCall: DispatchWorkItem?
var myImage: UIImage?
var imageUrlStr: String?
var someGlobalCass: SomeGlobalClass()    

@IBAction fileprivate func sendButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton){

   self.someGlobalClass.flag = true
   self.myImage = someFuncReturnsSomeImage()

   if let convertImage = self.myImage, let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(convertImage, 0.2){

     self.firstCall = DispatchWorkItem{ [weak self] in

         self?.storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {
                    (metadata, error) in

                    //if it gets here in less then 10 secs cancel the problemCall for the firstCall
                    self.problemCall?.cancel()

                    if let url = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString{
                        self.imageUrlStr = url
                    }

                    self.secondCall = DispatchWorkItem{ [weak self]  in

                        var imageDict = [String:Any]()
                        imageDict.updateValue(self.imageUrlStr, forKey: "imageUrlStr")

                        self?.dbRef.updateChildValues(imageDict(), withCompletionBlock: {
                                          (error, ref) in

                                           //if it gets here in less then 10 secs cancel the problemCall for the secondCall
                                           self.problemCall?.cancel()

                                           //if it reaches here were good
                                          self.wereGoodNowDoSomething()
                                          self?.someGlobalClass.flag = false
                        }
                    }

         /*>>>>>>APP GETS SHUT HERE DOWN BEFORE secondCall CAN PERFORM<<<<<<*/
                    self.secondCall?.perform()

                    //if the secondCall doesn't complete in 20 secs then cancel it
                    self.problemCall = DispatchWorkItem{ [weak self]  in
                         self?.secondCall?.cancel()
                         self?.someGlobalClass.flag = false
                         return
                    }
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 20, execute: self.problemCall!)

     }
     self.firstCall.perform()

     //if the firstCall doesn't run in 10 secs then cancel it
     self.problemCall = DispatchWorkItem{ [weak self]  in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.firstCall?.cancel()
                self?.someGlobalClass.flag = false
                //show alert for error
                return
            }
            return
     }
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10, execute: self.problemCall!)
   }
}
```

How do I handle the app getting shut down between steps 6 and 7 while the firstCall completes, the secondCall is running but it never completes and the problemCall never fires because the app is shut down?

**The issue is I now have image data sitting inside FB Storage, the url string never got sent to the database, and the global flag will now be set to true when it never reached a point to change it back to false.**

Btw in the callback I excluded the if error != nil. I'd cancel the problemCall there, set the global flag back to false, and then show an alert.

Comment: If the user shuts down the phone, what's the problem that is actually occurring?

Comment: @matt wouldn't the network call stop? Better yet if the phone shuts off right after the firstCall completes, my global flag is set to true and I have image data sitting in firebase storage that i can't use. I only want the flag set to true when the user presses the button and back to false when everything is completed. If the app is shut down and the user opens the app again it would be still be set to true.

Comment: Use `DispatchGroup` with its `notify` block. So you can get notified once first and second call is completed.

Comment: @ryan thanks for the assistance! Notify would still get called after the other 2 functions finish but if they don't finish because the app shut off it will never get called. Or am I missing something?